# Websphere MQ Server-To-Server-Connection with Apache ActiveMQ possible?

Tags: websphere, activemq-classic, mq

Does Apache Active MQ provide Server-To-Server-Connection as IBM Websphere MQ does?

Background:

We currently have Websphere MQ 7.0.1 (CUST) installed to communicate with another remote Websphere MQ Server (GOV), which is not under our control.
The MQs hold a Server-To-Server-Connection via VPN-tunnel. We would like to replace our Websphere MQ with Apache ActiveMQ.

We have one QM-Manager with 4 queues and 3 channels.

Queues:

1. OUT (type remote): for sending messages to GOV
2. QOUT (local type transmission) that is used for OUT
3. IMP  (local): used for receiving from GOV
4. DLQ: (local): dead letter queue

Channels:

1. conch: server connection
2. CUST_GOV: sender
3. GOV_CUST: receiver

I read a lot about bridging ActiveMQ to Websphere MQ (Client API, Resource Adapter, OSGi) with Camel.

Looks pretty easy with a Camel route, but this is at least a Client-Server setup.

E. G. https://www.shaishavparekh.com/2016/01/wmq-to-amq-bridge/

I need something that hides away the IBM proprietary channel stuff.

Now I found this entry: https://serverfault.com/questions/366743/apache-activemq-server-to-server-connection

As this is from 2012 I would like to ask, if anyone successful switched from Websphere MQ to ActiveMQ resp. is it still true that I can only use Client-Server?

Comment: Why do you "need something that hides away the IBM proprietary channel stuff"? How else would a WebsphereMQ client actually connect?

Comment: you're right, it's a wrong formulation. Simulation would be more what I meant. But as it's proprietary it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ does not support a server-to-server connection to WebsphereMQ. As you mentioned, Camel would probably be the simplest way to get a connection between the two brokers.

To be clear, even if ActiveMQ did implement a bridge with WebsphereMQ it would almost certainly use the WebsphereMQ client so would fundamentally still be a client-server implementation. It's not really clear from your question why you want to avoid this.

Comment: I did not set up the system by myself, but the reason why the Server-To-Server-Connection was set up was performance, as we have large amounts of messages already running for days once a year. The remote MQ is not under our control, so it would be much easier to leave the architecture as is without making change requests on GOV side. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Regardless of who set it up and why, ActiveMQ doesn't support it.

Comment: This was just the answer to your question why we want to avoid client mode. I'll mark your answer as the right one.